# A Balog-Szemeredi-Gowers-type question

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

A nice Lemma due to Konyagin asserts that for any subset $B \subset \mathbb{F}_p$ holds
$$
|B.B - B.B + B.B - B.B + B.B - B.B| \geq \frac{1}{2}\min\{p, |B|^2 \},
$$
where the standard notation for the product set $B.B$ is used. Now suppose that instead of $B.B$ we have a partial productset $B\stackrel{G}{.}B$ along the edges of a graph $G$ of edge density $\epsilon$ (meaning that $b_1b_2 \in B\stackrel{G}{.}B$ if only if $b_1, b_2 \in B$ are adjacent in $G$).

Is it true that if $B < \sqrt{p}$ a similar estimate
$$
 |B\stackrel{G}{.}B + B\stackrel{G}{.}B + B\stackrel{G}{.}B - B\stackrel{G}{.}B - B\stackrel{G}{.}B - B\stackrel{G}{.}B| \gg_{\epsilon} |B|^2 
$$
holds?

**UPD**
Sorry for sloppy notation. So what it means. $B.B = \{b_ib_j |b_i, b_j \in B \}$, 
$B.B-B.B = \{b_ib_j - b_kb_l |b_i, b_j, b_k, b_k \in B\}$, and $B.B+B.B$ etc. being defined the same way.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the notation. Can you please clarify it? There are a bunch of B.B's with plus and minus signs that seem to formally cancel.

Comment: @LevBorisov $B\cdot B=\{ab\mid a,b\in B\}$, $A\pm B=\{a\pm b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$. Also, writing $3(B\cdot B-B\cdot B)$ runs the risk of being ambiguous: Would this mean the set on the left of the display, or the set $\{3(ab-cd)\mid a,b,c,d\in B\}$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks for the comment, I have updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: It's still true by the usual argument (averaging over additive energies) that there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $|B+_G \lambda\cdot B|\geq\frac 12\min\{|G|,p\}$. After that Glibichuk and Konyagin's argument breaks down pretty badly. It's worth noting that they actually show that either $|(c-d)A+(a-b)A|\geq\frac 12\min\{|A|^2,p\}$ or $|(c-d)A+(a-b+c-d)A|\geq\frac 12\min\{|A|^2,p\}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are some elements of $A$.

Comment: Also, Bourgain's version of BSG might be helpful here, but I couldn't make it work straight away (see Bourgain's paper "On the Dimension of Kakeya Sets and Related Maximal Inequalities", or the last exercise in section 6.4 of Tao and Vu's book).

Comment: @BrendanMurphy Thanks for suggestions. I tried to approach the problem this way, like TGF Jones does in his thesis http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4853v1 (he uses the Bourgain version of BSG), but I don't see how to handle such complex combination of multiplication and addition.

Comment: If you could find $B'\subseteq B$ such that $|B'|>_\epsilon |B|$ and $B'.B'\subseteq B\cdot_G B$, that would prove the theorem. I don't see how to get the last condition, but Bourgain's theorem seems closest.

Comment: Brendan, unfortunately one cannot hope for a strict inclusion. Indeed, suppose in the additive case, that $B$ is an AP and $G$ is such that $B._GB$ contains only odd numbers. Then we cannot find $B'$ such that $B'+B' \subset B+_GB$ (it must contain even numbers), but of course BSG gives us $B'$ with comparable sumset size. However, I don't see how to control $|3B'B'-3B'B'|$ in terms of $|B'B'|$ only, since we inevitably have additional elements not in $B._GB$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sketch of a solution in a certain case.

Let $P$ be the set of pairs $(b,b')$ such that $|N_G(b)\cap N_G(b')|\approx_\epsilon |B|$ up to epsilons. Now let $Q=\{(b-b')/(c-c')\colon (b,b'),(c,c')\in P\}$. We need $\approx_\epsilon |B|^2$ such pairs (off the top of my head I'm not sure if this is possible, but I think it's a standard Cauchy-Schwarz argument).

Consider the special case $Q=\mathbb{F}_p$. Since the number of pairs $(b,b')$ is $\approx |B|^2$, we have
$$
|B|^4\approx \sum_{\lambda\in Q}E_+(B,\lambda\cdot B).
$$
Hence there is a $\lambda\in Q$ such that $E_+(B,\lambda\cdot B)\lesssim |B|^4/p$.

If $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $B$, then $E_+(S,\lambda\cdot T)\lesssim |B|^4/p$ since we can't get more quadruples by taking subsets. If $\lambda=(b-b')/(c-c')$, let $S$ be the neighborhood of $c-c'$ and let $T$ be the neighborhood of $b-b'$. Then
$$
|(c-c')\cdot S+(b-b')\cdot T|=|S+\lambda\cdot T|\geq \frac{|S|^2|T|^2}{E_+(S,\lambda T)}\gtrsim_\epsilon p.
$$
Now because $(c,x),(c',y)\in G$ for all $x,y\in S$ (and similarly for $b,b',T$), we have
$$
|B\cdot_G B-B\cdot_G B+B\cdot_G B-B\cdot_G B|\geq |cS-c'S+bT-b'T|\gtrsim p.
$$

Comment: It's a nice adaptation! Unfortunately, in the application I have in mind exactly the opposite case is crucial, i.e. when $|B|$ is small, and so is $B-B/B-B$.

Comment: Thanks! I think you could cover that case by a similar method. I'll add the details to the answer.

Comment: It indeed looks promising, but all my previous attempts failed at the point where we need to find to subsets $U$ and $W$ of moderate size, such that $U-U/U-U$ and $W-W/W-W$ are disjoint. The regularity lemma says that if only these sets are $\ll B$ then we can find sufficiently many pairs with large intersection of neigborhoods and we are done, but I didn't find a trick how to guarantee disjointness of the quotient sets (or at least that their intersection is small).

Comment: Actually, I think there are additional difficulties in this case. Although $Q\not=\mathbb{F}_p$ implies that there exists $\lambda\in Q$ such that $\lambda+1\not\in Q$, what we would need for the typical argument is $\lambda+1\not\in (B-B)/(B-B)$. Still you might be able to overcome this by examining the proof of BSG. I don't have tie to work it out now, however I wrote up an edit with a detailed version of the first case, if you would like it (I stopped once I realized the issue with the second case).

Comment: I don't know the regularity lemma so well, but we seem to be talking about a similar issue. Feel free to email me if you like.